# CakePHP Associated Models returning null?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, model, model-associations

I am having trouble with variables being returned having NULL values randomly.

I have this model association structure:

```
Truck   $hasOne  Chassis
Chassis $hasMany Make
Chassis $hasMany Model
Truck   $hasOne  Type
```

Randomly results will have null results for type or null results for make and model, but other results will have the correct results..

```
0 (array)
 Truck (array)
 Chassis (array)
  id 1
  make_id 2
  model_id 2
  title Basic Chassis
  description This Basic Chassis is good for a lot of things, but advanced stuff is not one..
 Truck_make (empty)
 Truck_model (empty)

1 (array)
 Truck (array)
 Chassis (array)
  id (null)
  make_id (null)
  model_id (null)
  title (null)
  description (null)
```

Above you can see that 2 trucks are loaded, the first one's chassis loaded and the make and model id's, but not the array's for the make and model.  Also the second vehicle had nothing load..

Here's a screenshot of associations from MySQL Workbench:
http://d.pr/i/JgMt

These are the queries that are called.

```
Query   Affected    Num. rows   Took (ms)   Actions
SELECT `Truck`.`id`, `Truck`.`chassis`, `Truck`.`type`, `Truck`.`title`, `Truck`.`ref`, `Truck`.`hide_truck`, `Truck`.`featured_gallery`, `Truck`.`featured_home`, `Truck`.`created`, `Chassis`.`id`, `Chassis`.`make_id`, `Chassis`.`model_id`, `Chassis`.`title`, `Chassis`.`description`, `Type`.`id`, `Type`.`title`, `Type`.`desc` FROM `douglass_cake`.`trucks` AS `Truck` LEFT JOIN `douglass_cake`.`chassis` AS `Chassis` ON (`Chassis`.`id` = `Truck`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `douglass_cake`.`types` AS `Type` ON (`Type`.`id` = `Truck`.`id`) WHERE 1 = 1    
SELECT `Truck_make`.`id`, `Truck_make`.`make`, `Truck_make`.`hide_make` FROM `douglass_cake`.`truck_makes` AS `Truck_make` WHERE `Truck_make`.`id` = (1)0   
SELECT `Truck_model`.`id`, `Truck_model`.`model`, `Truck_model`.`hide_model` FROM `douglass_cake`.`truck_models` AS `Truck_model` WHERE `Truck_model`.`id` = (1)
```

Comment: So I figured out the 'null' returns, it was mysql offset, but I still don't get why CakePHP is calling for the wrong rows for make and model..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out this issue.  Looks like MySQL Workbench wrote the tables with an offset of 2 instead of 1.  Cakephp was expecting the default offset so when the rows were returned to cakephp it read it starting at 1 while MySQL was told to start at 2.  FIxes.  Stupid error

Comment: @Ryamn How can we fix this problem?

Comment: @ManthanBudheliya I don't remember exactly.  I just changed the default offset.  Also, I no longer use MySQL workbench.